# Angular: Select dropdown with ng-model-options setter getter set to true

Tags: angularjs

Can somebody show me an example on how to bind `ng-options` to a getter and setter model, a `plnker` demo will be great.

Example on what i want to accomplish:

```js
// As you can see the item is a object with two properties example:
// {Text: "hello", Value: 10}

setgetObject: function(value) {
    if (angular.isDefined(value)) {
        myObject = angular.copy(value);  //copy the incoming object 
    }
    return ????
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="rumFra" ng-model="getterSetter.setgetObject"
   ng-options="item as item.Text for item in vm.configuration.Form.Room track by item.Value"
   ng-model-options=" {getterSetter: true }">
```

Each time I make a new selection on my dropdown it will set the `myObject` with the new value but the dropdown is not effected even if I return the input element.

A working example on how to use Select tag with `ng-options` and `ng-model-options="{setterGetter= "true"}"` will be appreciated :-)

Look at Numyx's example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SqJG8NP7e9NB9okcD4hN?p=preview

Because it is working but not with objects. Can somebody do it with objects?

Comment: THe example is not a working example

Comment: Do you want to get the selected value from the dropdown list?

Comment: Shouldn't the `setgetObject` just return the `myObject` variable? Working example using setterGetter: http://plnkr.co/edit/SqJG8NP7e9NB9okcD4hN?p=preview

Comment: Yes it is working, but can you do it with objects? instead of this.selected = [2, 3, 4, 5], can you use this.selected = [{Text: "hello10", Value: 10}, {Text: "hello11", Value: 11}, {Text: "hello12", Value: 12}]

Answer (score 0):

Just use [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) . ng-model binds the input,select and textareas.
see the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/494/)

```
<select ng-options="p.name for p in animal"
            ng-model="selectedanimal"></select>
```

Comment: this is it, if you can accomplish the same result with setterGetter